# Effective Force in a spinning bucket

Tags: rotation, centrifugal-force

If we consider a bucket of water spinning about it's symmetric axis with angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, and define a rotating polar coordinate system with origin at the bottom and center of the bucket, we should see that there are two contributing components to the effective force. A gravitational force in the $\hat{\textbf{z}}$ direction and a centrifugal force in the $\hat{\textbf{r}}$ direction.

$$\boldsymbol{F}_\text{eff} = mg\hat{\boldsymbol{z}} + m\omega^2r\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}$$

However, when I compute the centrifugal force for an arbitrary vector $\boldsymbol{r} = \langle r, \theta, z \rangle$, I find it has a $\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}$ component (using $\boldsymbol{\omega} =\langle 0, \omega, 0 \rangle$) :

$$\boldsymbol{F}_\text{cf} = -m\boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{r}) = \langle m\omega^2r, 0, m\omega^2z\rangle $$

So what's gone wrong here? There should not be a $\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}$ component of centrifugal force in this case as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{\omega}=\langle 0,0,\omega \rangle$ is oriented along the $z$ axis, not the $\theta$ axis.

Comment: Of course, I knew I was doing something wrong. Thanks!